# How to download V8 Issue Tracking DB?

Tags: chromium, v8, issue-tracking

http://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/list is the v8 javascript engine bugs tracker.
I want to download all issues data including list, comment and so on.
Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly not publicly available (apart from scraping the issue tracker). But someone has to administer the database, get in contact with them and ask for a (anonymised?) copy if you're interested in it for research purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge (I work on V8 and use that bug tracker as part of my daily work) this is not possible.

On the bright side, any copy would get outdated quickly; so from that point of view it makes more sense to work with the live instance anyway.

(Wild guess: you may be interested in running statistical queries over the bug database. Please be aware that it is very difficult to draw any reliable conclusions from such queries, as the bug tracker is a tool to organize many different kinds of work (actual bugs, feature requests, other tasks), and different people have different habits for how to use it or not use it. Feel free to play around, but do note that the underlying data is  most likely inaccurate, incomplete, and inconsistent, because nobody cares to spend time to make sure that it isn't.)

Comment: I want to create local v8 bug database to analyze v8 issues.Is it really impossible?